# Segmentation fault when trying to use a set function

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am having an issue with attempting to set a private data member in a node class. Here is the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class myType>
class node{
    private:
        myType data;
        node<myType>* next;
    public:

        // other functions

        void setData(myType p){
            data = p;
        }

        // other functions

};
```

Here is the class that attempts to use the node class:

```
template <class myType>
class LL{
    private:
        node<myType>* head;
        int index;
    public:

        // other functions            

        void addItem(myType d){
            node<myType>* p;
            p->setData(d);
            p->setNext(NULL);
            if(head == NULL){
                head = p;
            }
            else{
                node<myType> *temp;
                temp = head;
                head = p;
                head->setNext(temp);
            }
        }

        // other functions
};
```

The problem happens when attempting to use the setData function in the first node class. In the addItem function from the LL class, when p->setData is called, I get a segmentation fault. Through debugging I found that the segmentation fault happens once the program attempts to set data = p in the setData function. Any tips?

Comment: Ask yourself: what actual object does `node<myType>* p;` point to?

Comment: `node<myType>* p;` you better allocate a node before you attempt to access its members.

Comment: Pointers are like arrows drawn on a paper. If they don't point to anything they're kind of useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> node<myType>* p;
> ```

You've declared a pointer. You've not initialised the pointer, so it doesn't point to any node (neither does it point to null; the pointed memory address is indeterminate).

> ```
> p->setData(d);
> ```

Here, you dereference `p` to call a member function on the pointed object. But there is no pointed object, because you haven't created any node, and `p` doesn't point to any node. The behaviour of calling a member function of an uninitialised pointer is undefined (more generally, reading any indeterminate value has undefined behaviour).